# MapBox GL JS. Zoom to Altitude

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

How can I convert zoom lavel to altitude?

There is some kind of function 
or algorithm or table of values?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "altitude"? That is, are you trying to answer the question: "If my map is at zoom level `X`, what would the physical altitude of the camera object be if it were an actual camera placed in the real world?" Or, are you asking about the camera space height (in order to perform a programmatic manipulation of the camera)?

Comment: @AdrianaBabakanian Hi. Yes,  i trying to answer the question:" If my map is at zoom level X, what would the physical altitude of the camera object be if it were an actual camera placed in the real world?" OR "How to convert zoom lavel to meters" OR "If the layer has a maxzoom of 15 how many meters is it on the surface of the earth in 3d"

Answer (score 1):

There is a draft PR at https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/pull/8830 which adds a method to set the camera with an altitude, you could pull out some of that code to make your own method which returns a zoom level given an altitude.

Comment: there is no solution here

Comment: @KonstantinEmelyanov if you run the PR then you can simply do `map.transform.setCameraPosition({lng,lat,altitude,pitch,bearing})` or if you don't want to run the PR you could pull out the code and run it on a release of GL JS.

Comment: I pull out the code and run it on a release of GL JS. I made the getCameraPosition () function. But its values are not always accurate. I'm not sure about the mathematical algorithm for this solution.

Comment: Maybe somewhere there is a description of mathematical calculations for the zoom level to altitude translation

Comment: It would be nice to see a write up, it mostly just basic trigonometry plus understanding coordinate systems and web mercator.

I've tested it by comparing the resulting camera altitude set to the same height as an extruded polygon (in meters) and it matches up for me.

Answer (score 0):

Aside of the zoom level, the altitude of the camera (in meters) depends on the camera's Latitude postion. This [table](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/glossary/zoom-level/#zoom-levels-and-geographical-distance) gives some numbers. Maybe, based on that and some geometry, you might be able to derive a function which gives an estimate about the cameras altitude.

The keyword is 'estimate'. Calculating the precise altitude seems way more difficult since the earth is not a geometrically perfect ball.

For more general info check [here](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Zoom_levels)